# Minimum number of tables for ER diagram

Tags: database, relational-database, entity-relationship, dbms-output

I came across to an ER diagram

**Department(Dno,Dname,Phone,address)**
where phone and address are **multivalued** attributes.

[image: Image of my ER Diagram]

What is the **minimum** number of **tables** formed? Will it be 2 or 3?
According to me it should be 3 but answer is 2. 
Can anyone explain to me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify Primary key first. If I assume Dno is the PK then this attribute address and Phone can be divided into more columns, Such as address can be divided into City, Street, Zip and Phone can be divided into Phone1 Phone2. Such division will convert this Relation to 1NF as well as there will be no anomalies.